# Program spitting out axis errors due to one dimension being better, is it because of my final mix?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I made a program but it doesn't work, more detail later.

**The error**

```
  File "computer path", line 40, in <module>
    mix=np.concatenate((mix_ver, mix_hoz), axis=0)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 128 and the array at index 1 has size 1024
```

**My code**

```
# Import libs
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Final block size
blockSize = (128, 128)

# Air
air_small = cv2.imread('air.png', 1)
air = cv2.resize(air_small, blockSize)

# Dirt
dirt_small = cv2.imread('dirt.png', 1)
dirt = cv2.resize(dirt_small, blockSize)

# Grass
grass_small = cv2.imread('grass.png', 1)
grass = cv2.resize(grass_small, blockSize)

# Make mix ver
mix_ver=np.concatenate((grass, dirt),axis=0)
for m in range(2):
    mix_ver=np.concatenate((air, mix_ver),axis=0)

for m in range(4):
    mix_ver=np.concatenate((mix_ver, dirt), axis=0)

# Make mix hoz
    
mix_hoz=np.concatenate((grass, dirt),axis=1)
for m in range(2):
    mix_hoz=np.concatenate((air, mix_hoz),axis=1)

for m in range(4):
    mix_hoz=np.concatenate((mix_hoz, dirt), axis=1)

# Final Mix
mix=np.concatenate((mix_ver, mix_hoz), axis=0)

# Show output    
cv2.imshow('final', mix)
```

**What I think**

So as far as I know its the part at the end that is causing the problem, making it twice as big on the x axis, but not on the Y.
Is this correct?

**Notes**

1. Why am I resizing? I am resizing because my images are 64x64.
2. Why am I concatenating? I want to add these together so I can make a 2D area.

Comment: Because shape of mix_ver is (128,1024,3) and of mix_hoz is (1024,128,3)

Comment: What do you want to do with them? As they have more than 1 non-equal dimensions, they cannot be concatenated

Answer (score 1):

The image you are creating here:

```
# Make mix ver
mix_ver=np.concatenate((grass, dirt),axis=0)
for m in range(2):
    mix_ver=np.concatenate((air, mix_ver),axis=0)

for m in range(4):
    mix_ver=np.concatenate((mix_ver, dirt), axis=0
```

is concatenated along the vertical axis (rows), so it becomes a shape like this:

```
|_|
|_|
|_|
...
```

while the second created image is concatenadet along horizontal dimension (columns) and looks like this:

```
|_|_|_|...
```

In the line that is throwing the error, you are trying to concatenate them into one image, which is not possible (as you can imagine). You need to let us know what you are trying to achieve (what shape you want to have for your final image).

---

On a different note: You are concatenating `grass` and `dirt` one time together, but then you are adding 2 times `air` and 4 times `dirt` again, I'm not sure if this is the desired outcome.

Comment: Yes I noticed the second note, but on I want to achieve is a square of land.

Comment: what I want to achieve*

Comment: nvm I fixed the problem.

Comment: how? could you let us know? In particular, what do you mean with a square of land?

Comment: what I did now was I placed the vertical plane 4 times in the horizontal axis, this makes a square. What I did before would've made a weird shape that doesn't make a square at all. I fixed the program and it now works.